# wrong reported Total Sum of Squares in time fixed effects with plm (twoways)

Tags: r, plm

The summary command of a plm regression with the (`effect="twoways"`) argument reports the same coefficients as a plm regression with manual time dummies (and the default `effect="individual"`) but a much lower total sum of squares (and therefore a much lower R2). Why is this the case?

**Example:**

```
library(plm)

individual <- c(rep("AT",5),rep("BE",5),rep("DE",5))
time <- c(rep(2006:2010,3))
set.seed(123)
y <- c(rep(rnorm(15, sd=2)))
x <- c(rep(rnorm(15, sd=3)))

Test <- data.frame(individual=individual, time=time, x=x, y=y)
year.f = factor(Test$time)
dummies = model.matrix(~year.f)
Test <- cbind(Test,dummies)
remove(dummies,year.f)

fe_manual <- plm(y~ x+year.f2007+year.f2008+year.f2009+
year.f2010,data=Test,model="within")
summary(fe_manual)

fe_twoways <- plm(y~ x, data=Test,model="within",effect="twoways")
summary(fe_twoways)
```

The problem doesn't look very bad here (we go from total sum of squares of 38.7 in the manual model to 30.1 in the twoways model), but in my real sample, this problem gets me from an R2 of 42% to one of 3%. The problem gets much bigger with more data.

Any help would be appreciated!

edit: You can see that the twoways model calculates time fixed effects by running:

```
fixef(fe_twoways)
```

Strangely, these coefficients are again different from the manual model.

Comment: This appears to be just a statistical question with no real coding issues apparent to me.

Comment: hm, I don't think so because I cannot believe that there is a real statistical issue here (plm is a very standard package). It must have something to do with the routine of plm. But where could I move the question so it fits better?

Comment: `fixef()` returns, by default, the fixed effects in levels. To compare to your `lm()` results, use the deviations from the first (time) fixed effect: `fixef(fe_twoways, "time", type = "dfirst")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, in contrast to the `lfe-package`, the `plm-package` does not report $R^2$ and adjusted $R^2$ for the full model, but only for the projected model. [This](http://karthur.org/2016/fixed-effects-panel-models-in-r.html) blog-entry should answer your question.

Comment: I'd like to point out as well that this problem is always solvable by adding an `+ as.factor(time)` or + `as.factor(individual)` to the model which then includes the explained sum of squares of those dummies.